# React tutorial raising type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React from [official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Constructor Comment requires 'new' react.js:5970
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. My source code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
     <title>Hello World</title>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">        
      </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js">     
      </script>

      <script type="text/babel">
         // tutorial8.js
        var data = [
                {id: 1, author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
                {id: 2, author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
                ];

    var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div className="commentBox">
                    <h1>Comments</h1>
                    <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
                </div>);
        }
    });

    var CommentList = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
                return (
                    <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
                        {comment.text}
                    </Comment>);
            });
            return (
                <div className="commentList">
                    {commentNodes}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

   // Always the last step.
   ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox data={data} />,
       document.getElementById('content'));
</script>
```

Comment: its cause you dont have Comment as a component in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is actually quite simple. 
All you're missing is the code to create the Comment component. You may want it to look something like this based on how you've set up your CommentBox.

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentContainer">
                <div className='commentAuthor'>{this.props.author}</div>
                <div className='commentText'>{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a React component for every component you use, you do not have one for `Comment` here. If you look at tutorial 4 you see that they make it there.

Each 'tutorial' here isnt a standalone example.

Comment: Thanks!! I missed that. I started learning React a day before and I messed up.